# How to specify language on Google Place API for iOS

Tags: ios, swift, google-api, google-places-api

I'm using GMSAutocompleteViewController.

It can search address by input-form in Japanese.
And API display a lists written by Japanese.

But the name of the Place choosen is in English.

Please tell me how to specify a language on Google Place API for iOS.

```
func viewController(_ viewController: GMSAutocompleteViewController, didAutocompleteWith place: GMSPlace) {

    print(place)
    print("Place name: \(place.name)") //<- I want a Japanese,but English
    print("Place address: \(place.formattedAddress)")
    print("Place attributions: \(place.attributions)")
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: you want name of place written in japanese language??

Comment: Yes,that's right.

Comment: did you find an answer?